# How can i use "like" in linq to xml

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I wanna do something like this. I know it’s wrong:

```
 var a = from h in xdoc.Root.Elements()
         where h.Element().value like = "1234"
         select h;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var a = from h in xdoc.Root.Elements()
        where h.Element.value.Contains("1234") 
        select h
```

This would generate a 'LIKE' statement in the background.

Comment: thx alot thats working perfectly. and how can i do that h.Element.Name?? coz Element.Name doest have "Contains".

Comment: any string in .NET should have a Contains method.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you want to get the elements that [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.contains.aspx) the `1234` value:

```
var a = from h in xdoc.Root.Elements()
         where h.Element().Value.Contains("1234") // like '%1234%'
         select h;
```

For the SQL-ish  `like '%value'` you can use [EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx), and for `like 'value%'` [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the helper methods of the String class, like `StartsWith` or `EndsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use StartsWith() method to do the same.

```
var CountryNames = from city in xdoc.Descendants("countries").Elements("city")                         
                           where city.Value.StartsWith(prefixText)
                           select city.Value;
```

[Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.contains.aspx)

[EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx)

[StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx)